# Autopopulate a new field with Account Name when I add a contact through a Lookup field

Tags: lightning, formula, custom-object

I want a custom new field called "Organization" to auto-populate with "Account Name" related to the contact I add in my look-up field called "Class host":

To paint the picture:

Anne works at an organization called HAPPY.

I create a class/campaign and add Anne as "Class host" through my look-up field that feeds from "contacts".
Then field "Organization" automatically populates to say "HAPPY", the account name = organization Anne works at.

How do I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure about the data model, nor if this is in Lightning, but have you checked the `defaultFieldValues` as described here: https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-for-lightning-tutorial/ ?

I would suggest you to edit your question to explain what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you need is formula field of type TEXT on your **class/campaign** object. It will be populated with Contact's (Class host) Account Name field.
[image]